# Mostrar mensaje al validar dos campos en formularios Django3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo un formulario donde valido que dos campos no tengan la misma información

La idea es que al darle al botón Save del formulario haga dicha validación, mostrando un mensaje, 
una notificación, una alerta whatever, indicando que ambos campos no pueden ser iguales

Ambos campos son claves foráneas que apuntan a un mismo modelo, de modo que los dos campos obtienen un id de dicho modelo
pero no puede ser el mismo para ambos campos.

Siguiendo la documentación oficial de Django, creé una funcion en el form.py y en el models.py,
ambas deberían hacer esto, sin embargo no sucede.

Probé también esto: 'from django.contrib import messages' en el models.py pero no funcionó tampoco, aunque me pareció bastante bueno.

Este es el code del forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from app_test.models import stock_move


class stock_move_form(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = stock_move

        fields = [
           'location_id',
            'location_dest_id',
            ]

        labels = {
            'location_id': 'Move From',
            'location_dest_id': 'Move To',
        }

        widgets = {
            'location_id': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'location_dest_id': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        location_id = cleaned_data.get("location_id")
        location_dest_id = cleaned_data.get("location_dest_id")

        if location_id == location_dest_id:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "The destination location can no be the same "
                "as origin, please check the locations of the form "
            )
```

Y este es el code de models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from app_test.models import stock_location

class stock_move(models.Model):

    location_id = models.ForeignKey(stock_location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location_dest_id = models.ForeignKey(stock_location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')


    def clean(self):

        if self.location_id == self.location_dest_id:
            raise ValidationError(_("The destination location can no be the same "
                                    "as origin, please check the locations of the form "))
```

Ambos tienen la función clean(), y cuando en el formulario selecciono ambos campos iguales me lanza este error:

```
ValueError at /function_create_stock_move/
The view app_test.views.function_create_stock_move didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Y este es el codigo de Views.py:

```
class function_create_stock_move(CreateView):

    stock_move_model = stock_move
    product_package_model = products_package
    form_class = stock_move_form
    template_name = 'warehouse/stock_move/functions/function_create_stock_move.html'   
    success_url =  reverse_lazy('view_list_stock_move')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.object = self.get_object
        data_stock_move = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if data_stock_move.is_valid(): 
            move = data_stock_move.save(commit=False)
            location_dest_id = move.location_dest_id.id
            if move.package_id:
                package_id = move.package_id.id
                product_package = self.product_package_model.objects.get(id=package_id)
                product_package.location_id_id = location_dest_id
                product_package.save()
            move.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
]
```

Significa que de alguna manera valida que no sean iguales los campos pero recibo ese error.
Quizá tengo que hacer algún return Http... en las funciones pero no veo eso es la documentacion Django.

Pienso que también podría ser que debo integrarlo al template, pero si es así ¿Como?

PD: Me sirve también usar las validaciones por defecto del método .is_valid() de los formularios, no sé si eso pueda 
sobreescribirse o modificarse, no conseguí documentación acerca de eso.

Quedo atento a sus comentarios

Comment: Primero que nada las validaciones te deberían funcionar si ningún problema, por otra parte el error ocurre en la vista `function_create_stock_move`, algo mal estas haciendo en dicha vista, según el error no estas retornando nada y debes retornar algo (`HttpResponse`).

Comment: Como te dije anteriormente las validaciones deberían funcionar, te sugiero editar esta pregunta y re-formularla re-planteando el problema especifico que tienes, pues el inconveniente o problema no tiene que ver con la validación de formulario, tiene que ver con la vista (y de ser posible adjunta el código de la vista).

Comment: Agregado el código del views.py. Sigo con el mismo error, aun lo logro  dar con el porque.

Comment: Estoy probando copiando tu código y lo probé y todo funciona correctamente, estas seguro que no funciona? De ser posible pon el error completo.

Comment: De tanto buscar la manera, logré hacerlo pero con una vista basada en función, usando messages de Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESUELTO

creé un archivo aparte llamado validations.py, donde definí algunas validaciones adicionales, entre ellas la que necesitaba para este caso:

Una vez creado el objeto (move) reviso si el id de las ubicaciones (locations) son iguales.

```
if move.location_dest_id.name == move.location_id.name:
    errors.append(
        'La ubicación Destino no puede ser la misma '
        'que el Origen.')
```

El resultado del error lo agrego a una lista de mensajes de error. Esta lista la devuelve la función, si la lista contiene errores, las notifico al usuario